# Socket.io something like ajax

Tags: node.js, http, socket.io, request

I'm trying to get data from web page but I can't find solution. Here is socket server side code:

```js
function get_page(url) {
    //function which return web page data
}
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    result=get_page('http://example.com');
    io.sockets.emit('data',result);
});
```

Comment: What does this mean: "socket server before emit data must check it on another page"?  Please explain in a lot more words (and probably some code) what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to do something like this:
`io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
 $.ajax({url: "http://example.com", success: function(result){
io.sockets.emit('data',result);
}});
});`

Comment: Please edit your question to put appropriate code and description in the question itself.  On stack overflow, it is your responsibility to write a good question and the community will remove it (with downvotes and closevotes) if you do not.  Also, it is not appropriate to post a question and then only come back here 18 hours later.  This is a faily realtime site, not like a BBS where you post and come back the next day.  Please read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the Help Center here.

Comment: Also, please make it clear whether your code is running in the browser or in a server-side environment like node.js.  The snippet of code you put in your previous comment looks like part server code and part client code.  Very unclear.  Fix your question to be clear please.  Use the "edit" link to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just asking how to implement `get_page()`, you can either use `http.get()` or a bit easier to use [`request` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request).  Using the `request` module, your nodejs code could look like this:

```
let request = require('request');

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    // upon initial connection, fetch some data and send it to the connecting client
    request('http://example.com', function(err, response, body) {
         if (err) {
             // send some error response here
             socket.emit('data', "example.com not responding - no data available");
         } else {
             // send data to the connecting socket
             socket.emit('data', body);
         }
    });
});
```